# Using xpath with python lxml to query html

Tags: python, html, xml, xpath, lxml

I am reading a html page as a string and use `tree = html.fromstring(data)`

I now want to use lxml xpath to query. Below are an example of the part i am interested in.

```
<table class="class">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <th class="classTh">
    Overall
   </th>
   <td class="classTd">
    <span class="classSpan">
     GREEN
    </span>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

with the call

```
 xpath = '//table/tbody/tr[th="Overall"]/td/span'
 e = tree.xpath(xpath)
  for i in e:
   print(i.text)
```

I am using xpath to get the data i need. But i cannot get the xpath to work. Using this exact code + xpath in any online tester works for me.

I have tried with xpath:

```
xpath = '//table/tbody/tr[th]/td/span'
```

which gets me all elements instead of the ones with the correct filter value.

```
 xpath ='//table/tbody/tr[td/span]/th'
```

gets me all the filter values.

So my question. How to i apply the text value filter in my xpath correctly?

Comment: When you try it with online XPath tester you handle webpage with already executed JavaScript, while your table might be generated dynamically and HTTP libraries like `requests`, `urllib`, etc could only provide you with page source without JavaScript executed

Comment: Because the 2 latest xpath queries works to confirm the data i'm querying against is correct i didn't think it would be any problem with the data itself. Instead i am under the impression its a problem with the query. Or am I missing the point? :)

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for this xpath in lxml is the following:

```
xpath = "//table/tbody/tr[th[contains(text(), 'Overall')]]/td/span"
```

Which solved my problem.